# Cant disable beta transforms warnings in PyTorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

Win x64, Spyder, Python 3.9, Pytorch 2.0.1+cu117

Reams of

```
C:\Users\sengnr3\.conda\envs\pytorch\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\v2\__init__.py:54: UserWarning: The torchvision.datapoints and torchvision.transforms.v2 namespaces are still Beta. 
While we do not expect major breaking changes, some APIs may still change according to user feedback. Please submit any feedback you may have in this issue: 
https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/6753, and you can also check out https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/7319 to learn more about the APIs that we suspect might involve future changes. 
You can silence this warning by calling torchvision.disable_beta_transforms_warning().
      warnings.warn(_BETA_TRANSFORMS_WARNING)
```

So I try & silence using the advice in the warning
Code,

```
import torchvision
torchvision.disable_beta_transforms_warning()
```

But still reams of the same warning.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like to disable v2 warning you need to call `disable_beta_transforms_warning()` first then import the `v2` transform.

For example, this code won't disable the warning:

```
from torchvision.transforms import v2
import torchvision
torchvision.disable_beta_transforms_warning()
```

But this code does:

```
import torchvision
torchvision.disable_beta_transforms_warning()
from torchvision.transforms import v2
```

If you import `v2` transform first, it will make a warning because python import the `v2` transform first without disabling the warning.